# What are semantic word spaces in NLP?

Tags: natural-language-processing, terminology, papers

In the abstract of [this paper](https://aclanthology.org/D13-1170.pdf), it's written

> **Semantic word spaces** have been very useful but cannot express the meaning of longer phrases in a principled way.

I would like to understand what **semantic word spaces** are. I find [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_space) explanation unsatisfactory:

> Semantic spaces in the natural language domain aim to create representations of natural language that are capable of capturing meaning.

How exactly are these representations computed? For example, if we take the sentence

> I like reading books.

What would be its semantic word space? Or am I confusing semantic **word** spaces with semantic spaces here?